# ProLiant SE316M1 + Intel S3500 SSD + Smart Array P410 512MB. Battery (BBWC) needed?

Tags: hp-proliant, ssd, hp-smart-array, intel, bbwc

I'm looking to replace our SQL Server:

> HP Proliant DL360 G4
>   2x 64-bit Intel Xeon 3.60 GHz, 1M Cache, 800 MHz FSB
>   4GB RAM DDR2
>   HP Smart Array 6i
>   2x 146GB SCSI 15K (RAID 1)

With this:

> HP ProLiant SE316M1
>   2x Intel Xeon L5520 (8M Cache, 2.26 GHz, 5.86 GT/s Intel QPI)
>   Nehalem
>   16GB RAM DDR3
>   HP Smart Array P410 512 MB BBWC Cache
>   2 x 120GB Intel DC S3500 SSD (RAID 1)

I'm also upgrading from SQL Server 2000 and Windows 2003 to SQL Server 2008 R2 and Windows 2008 R2.

I understand the SE316M1 is basically a DL160 G6.

I know our current setup is so ancient (10-year-old) that almost anything can be a big improvement. And this new setup is not a big deal either (5-year-old and pretty unexpensive). But I want to do something as good as I can with my limited budget, but also very reliable.

My biggest concern is the P410 Smart Array and the SSDs (Intel DC S3500).
I understand they're compatible, the S3500 is a decent and reliable SSD, and that the P410 won't be a bottleneck for the SSDs.

But what is the Battery Backed Write Cache (BBWC) Module for? Is it a must? What would I be missing in this setup if I don't have it?
I'm reading this: [HP Smart Array P400/256MB SAS Controller BATTERY](https://serverfault.com/questions/359623/hp-smart-array-p400-256mb-sas-controller-battery). Would I loose performance whith those Intel SSDs? The server will be protected with a UPS. Sorry, I'm a bit confused here! Thanks!

Comment: Typically a migration is a fair bit of effort in an enterprise and going from Windows 2003 to Windows 2008 rather than skipping that and going straight to Windows 2012 seems like trading up your horseless carriage to  a Model-T Ford when the same amount of effort would get allow you to get, say a Tesla.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need a BBWC on any Smart Array controller in which you wish to use SSD drives.

http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c02963968